# Size issue after redirection

Tags: angular, sass

I'm trying to do a component which needs to take the whole screen.
I tried to put it at width 100% and height 100% and it doesn't work.
I'm using angular (with electron).

By a click on a link on a page, i'm redirected into another component. And this component is not taking the whole screen.
I would like to access to the body, to change for instance the background-color but I can't access it.

```
body {
  color: $f-color;
  font-family: $ff-default;
  margin: 0;
  background: $dark;
}
```

(And my variables are in another file)

my app.component.html :

```
<div style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

After a click on the home component i'm redirected to another component.

For example, the body element in my style.scss file is black and after the redirection I want to pass it to red but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :host selector in your component .scss

```
:host {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```